# How to receive emails of the same inbox from multiple server instances

Tags: email

I have an application running on WebLogic Server with 6 instances. Many requests for the application come from Email. We already set up an email account that will be used by all clients to send email to. But the problem is that the email account inbox can only be opened for reading by a single connection, unlike a typical database.
Currently I can only deploy the email reading service on a single server instance, this will effectively create a single point of failure and unbalanced load. What's the best way to read from the same inbox from multiple servers? I am thinking developing something using a database table, sort of leasing, whoever locked the table own the lease and can connect to the email server, but this is pretty hard to implement correctly in all circumstances.

Comment: What is your email server running on? Is it POP or IMAP based?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think it's POP.

Comment: Just double checked, it is POP3

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you say that only one client can access the inbox as POP certainly can handle multiple connections to the same inbox and this can be configured in the mail server. You might need to talk to your mail server admin.

I haven't worked with Weblogic to give you a specific answer, but you should also be able to have a service written that checks the incoming mail and process incoming mails into a database as you wanted. Once the information is in a database, you can use it via multiple hosts. This is a better approach as this can be setup to prevent multiple clients responding to the same email.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I really don't know POP well. If multiple connections to the same inbox is possible, I guess my question would be transactional behavior, which is to guarantee to read the same email only once. Does POP3 prevent multiple clients from reading the same email at the same time?

Comment: I think the connection restriction is done at the server level. Don't know much about the details. I don't think it is able to do the locking at the email level. But using a single client to read the email stream and populate the database would be the safer option. I know that this is possible with Sendmail in linux and have seen some in work. There should be lots of resources out there.